# Using Slick or something similar to convert PHP image loop to JS with lazy load

Tags: javascript, php, slick.js

I'm trying to use Slick, the JS image carousel tool, but apply it to what I have in an existing PHP loop of images. I want two things here:

a. A carousel of images so that only a few are shown and can be cycled through
b. Lazy loading

I have this PHP image loop:

```
<?php foreach ($imageResult as $im): ?>
  <?php if($im['type'] == 'content'){?>
    <img src="<?php echo $im['url']; ?>" style="max-width:200px; max-height:200px;">
 <?php } ?>
<?php endforeach?>
```

But I'm unsure of how to take my `$imageResult` object coming from my database and incorporate it into something like this from slick:

```
<img data-lazy="img/lazyfonz1.png"/>

$('.lazy').slick({
  lazyLoad: 'ondemand',
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 1
});
```

Comment: Checkout https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/

Comment: Does that have lazy load and buttons/arrows though? I don't need touch functionality but I definitely need lazy loading

Comment: yes, it has all of that and even more. Checkout the demo link they have